# Looking for a concept related to "either or" in a data structure (almost like std::variant)

Tags: c++, dataformat

I'm modernizing the code that reads and writes to a custom binary file format now.
I'm allowed to use C++17 and have already modernized large parts of the code base.

There are mainly two problems at hand.

1. binary selectors (my own name)
2. cased selectors (my own name as well)

For #1 it is as follows:
Given that 1 bit is set in a binary string. You either (read/write) two completely different structs.
For example, if bit 17 is set to true, it means bits 18+ should be streamed with Struct1.
But if bit 17 is false, bits 18+ should be streamed with Struct2.
Struct1 and Struct2 are completely different with minimal overlap.

For #2 it is basically the same but as follows:
Given that x bits in the bit stream are set. You have a potential pool of completely different structs. The number of structs is allowed to be between [0, 2**x] (inclusive range).
For instance, in one case you might have 3 bits and 5 structs.
But in another case, you might have 3 bits and 8 structs.
Again the overlap between the structs is minimal.

I'm currently using `std::variant` for this.

For case #1, it would be just two structs `std::variant<Struct1, Struct2>`

For case #2, it would be just a flat list of the structs again using `std::variant`.

The selector I use is naturally the index in the variant, but it needs to be remapped for a different bit pattern that actually needs to be written/read to/from the format.

Have any of you used or encountered some better strategies for these cases?
Is there a generally known approach to solve this in a much better way?

Comment: Basically you'd like an 'intrusive' variant?

Comment: Does the code get/receive the binary stream and decode it or does it represent/store the stream. May it do so in an expanded fashion - e.g. copy the bitfields into other variables or should the bitfield stay compressed. Should the class be/represent a different class to the outside (having a specific interface) depending on the selection or is it about internal stuff like storage/validation/encoding?

Comment: @lorro intrusive_variant seems interesting, but it's not part of C++17, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Sebastian The code I work on now is packing/unpacking a compressed data structure to/from disk or memory. Naturally, the data structures that are exposed in the public API are more verbose.
So, yes, in one sense the data can be described more verbosely in the end. But the low-level writing and reading where I work now there's a need to do so in a less verbose way. I think of it as "tokenizing" for grammar. The tokenizer itself isn't that verbose, but the grammar can be quite verbose.

Comment: @DecafSux No, it's a made-up term to describe the situation. Basically, the variant wrapper would have an underlying type, from which it can query the actual type. You can also add visit to the underlying type.

Comment: @lorro Ah, I see I had to read up on it and it is actually mentioned some time ago in cppcon. But I couldn't see if it was part of the standard or just some proposal.

Comment: Note that most implementations of standard library prefer performance over bit economy. For example std::string small string optimisation is like your case 1. but most implementations only manage to store up to 15 character strings in 32 byte objects locally. That could conceivably be up to 30 character strings if to save every bit possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a generally known approach to solve this in a much better way?

Nope, it's highly specific.

> Have any of you used or encountered some better strategies for these cases?

The bit patterns should be encoded in the type, somehow. Almost all the (de)serialization can be generic so long as the required information is stored somewhere.

For example,

```
template <uint8_t BitPattern, typename T>
struct IdentifiedVariant;

// ...

using Field1 = std::variant< IdentifiedVariant<0x01, Field1a>,
                             IdentifiedVariant<0x02, Field1b> >;
```

I've absolutely used types like this in the past to automate all the boilerplate, but the details are extremely specific to the format and rarely reusable.

---

Note that even though you can't overlay your variant type on a buffer, there's no need for (de)serialization to proceed bit-by-bit. There's hardly any speed penalty so long as the data *is* already read into a buffer - if you really need to go full zero-copy, you can just have your `FieldNx` types keep a pointer into the buffer and decode fields on demand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be bit-continuous you can't use `std::variant` You will need to use `std::bitset` or managing the memory completely manually to do that. But it isn't practical to do so because your structs will not be byte-aligned so you will need to do every read/write manually bit by bit. This will reduce speed greatly, so I only recommend this way if you want to save every bit of memory even at the cost of speed. And at this storage it will be hard to find the nth element you will need to iterate.

`std::variant<T1,T2>` will waste a bit of space because 1) it will always use enough space for storing the the bigger data, but using that over bit-manipulation will increase the speed and the readability of the code. (And will be easier to write)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I can waste a little bit of space but the code is fairly low-level, so it has to be within reason. Maybe readability will be preferred for the sake of maintenance, but I will read up more on std::bitset. Thank you :-)